# CSS Auto Resizing Grid Height

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on a modal that is created through PHP. The issue I'm running into is sizing, specifically the sizing of the height of the modal. The directions found inside of the modal could be in varying length, so I can't stick with a static height like "350px" since every set of directions will be different word lengths. Additionally, I have to adjust the height of the div with Javascript whenever the user clicks the "Ask for Help" button since this function adds a textbox to the modal.

**Desired end result:** A modal that's height is set to fit just the contents displayed, no extra white space. I want to eliminate all the extra white space between the directions and the buttons, essentially.

**What I've tried** I've adjusted the `.modal-window{height: }` property to both 100%, auto, and 1fr, but none of these seem to work. Additionally, I'm not sure how I would resize the `.modal-window` to adjust for the added textbook if the user clicks the "ask for help" button. I've ran out of ideas, what do I need to do?

Codepin: https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/VwbYdMJ

**Example image of desired outcome:** [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft5Xe.png)

```js
function askHelp(arg) {
  
  var window = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-window')[0];
  var textbox = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  
  var helpBtn = document.getElementById('askforhelp');
  var doneBtn = document.getElementById('markdone');
  var sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendmsg');
  var cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancelmsg');
  
  if (arg == "showform") {
    window.style.height = '400px';
    textbox.style.display = 'block';
    helpBtn.style.display = 'none';
    doneBtn.style.display = 'none';
    sendBtn.style.display = 'block';
    cancelBtn.style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  if (arg == "hideform") {
    window.style.height = '350px';
    textbox.style.display = 'none';
    helpBtn.style.display = 'block';
    doneBtn.style.display = 'block';
    sendBtn.style.display = 'none';
    cancelBtn.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {display: block !important}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  right: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s}

/* Customized part listed below */

.modal-window{
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 600px; height: 350px;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: height 0.5s;
  grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "top"
    "content"
    "controls";}

/* --------[TOP] -------- */
.modal-top {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: top; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #5B7042;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 80px;}

.pic{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 65px;
  clip-path: circle();
  margin-left: 10px;}

.modal-top .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 26px}

.due {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: gray;}


/* --------[CONTENT] -------- */
.modal-content {
  display: block;
  grid-area: content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 12px;}

.directions {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.7}

textarea {
  display: none;
  width: 100%; height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  margin-top: 20px;}

/* --------[CONTROLS] -------- */
.modal-controls {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  grid-area: controls}

#askforhelp {margin-right: 10px;}

#sendmsg {display: none; margin-right: 10px}
#cancelmsg {display: none}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">

<div id="successModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-window">
    <div class='modal-top'>
      <img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'>
      <span class='title'> Reading Homework </span>
      <span class='due'> Due 3d </span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class='directions'>
        <b>Directions:</b> You must complete this assignment to continue to the next section.
      </div>
      <textarea placeholder='Type Question..'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-controls">
      <button id='askforhelp' class='button green-btn' onclick='askHelp("showform")'>Ask for Help</button>
      <button id='markdone' class='button green-btn'>Mark as Done</button>
      <button id='sendmsg' class='button green-btn'>Send Message</button>
      <button id='cancelmsg' class='button grey-btn' onclick='askHelp("hideform")'>Cancel Message</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example image of desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ZPW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
height:100vh;
```

or Use calc() to calculate

```
height:calc(100vh - 100px);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, that would actually do the exact opposite of what I want to do. 100vh would add even more white space. I want to eliminate unnecessary white space, and make the modal as small as possible.

Comment: height:auto; ??

Comment: I explained in the post that ```auto``` does not work because it does not accommodate the textbox inserted with javascript..